# Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task IN AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

I am not getting any error in local with node-fetch in the package.json also have node-fetch dependencies but when I deployed in aws lambda then this dependencies not found.
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/query1.js\n- /var/task/query1Main.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/query1.js",
    "- /var/task/query1Main.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare external packages as layers for a lambda
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Node version `18.x` and fixed after downgrading to `16.x`

This can be done in the lambda page -> scroll down to `Runtime settings`

I hope you already resolved the issue but I'm posting this in case someone else finds it useful.

Comment: Did not solve for me :/